# Date Picker View Super Small - Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, date, uitoolbar, picker

I've got a view controller with different textfields, two of which are for dates. I'm trying to make a date picker appear when the user taps in the text field, for ease of use. For some reason, the date picker looks like this:

[image]

I don't know why the image is so big on stack overflow lol

Here is my code:

```
    func createDatePicker() {
        // toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.delegate = self
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        
        // bar button
//        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
        
        // assign toolbar to textviews
        lossDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        dateTakenTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        
        // assign date picker to textfields
        lossDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
        dateTakenTextField.inputView = datePicker
        
    }
```

I set the text field delegate to self in viewDidLoad and call the createDatePicker function there as well.

Why is it appearing like this instead of how it's supposed to?

Note: I am using IQKeyboardManagerSwift in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add bellow code and your date picker will work fine.

```
       if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePicker!.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate you taking a moment to respond.